# Convert SVG to PNG with Classic ASP and ImageMagick

Tags: asp-classic, svg, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to convert SVG to PNG with ImageMagick.

SVG conversion to PNG worked perfectly from command line:

```
Convert -size 200x200 svglogo.svg generatedimage.png
```

It produced a .png I was expecting.

Yet,

```
Img.Convert "-size", "200x200", "C:\myApp\temp\svglogo.svg", "C:\myApp\temp\pleasemakethiswork.png"
```

produced a blank .png with nothing more than a white background.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Img.Convert "C:\myApp\temp\svglogo.svg", "-resize=200x200", "C:\myApp\temp\pleasemakethiswork.png"